# Is it possible to return multiple SignalRMessageActions from a serverless Azure Function?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-signalr

I've got a function with a `CosmosDBTrigger` and I want to pipe notifications out to SignalR clients. The Cosmos trigger gives you an IEnumerable of items, which may belong to multiple different clients, I've tried returning a `List<SignalRMessageAction>` but I get a serialization error. Is it possible to return multiple items from a function using `[SignalROutput]` ?

```
public class UpdatesAvailableFunction
{
    [Function(nameof(UpdatesAvailableFunction))]
    [SignalROutput(HubName = "serverless", ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureSignalRConnectionString")]
    public List<SignalRMessageAction> UpdatesAvailable(
        [CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "%DatabaseName%",
            collectionName: "%ContainerName%",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "ConnectionString",
            LeaseCollectionName = "leases",
            LeaseCollectionPrefix = "UpdatesAvailable")]
        IReadOnlyList<BrowserFeedNotification> input)
    {
        return input.Select(x => new SignalRMessageAction("updatesAvailable")
        {
            UserId = x.UserId
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

The error message I'm getting is

> [2022-11-04T11:01:32.319Z] Executed 'Functions.UpdatesAvailableFunction' (Failed, Id=b7ebfc4a-40cc-48ef-9f31-52c7c414daf3, Duration=15342ms)
> [2022-11-04T11:01:32.320Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.UpdatesAvailableFunction. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService: Unable to convert JObject to valid output binding type, check parameters.

Comment: Try creating new list and assign those values https://github.com/John-ltf/IoT-app/blob/b3d90e1222c97eb0245a64aef100c82c8cd2cce1/IoT-functions/IoTTelemetryData.cs#L293

Comment: @Sajeetharan thanks for your comment. That's basically what I'm doing with the call to `ToList()` at the end of the return line. The consumer (in this case,  Azure Functions) doesn't know or care how the list was created, just that it's being given a list.

Comment: Another way is described here: https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/functions-isolated-worker-sending-multiple-messages